# console log phpstorm выводится при выделенной переменной

Tags: phpstorm, консоль

Узнал что  есть livetemplate для phpstorm , набираешь свой шаблон, cl -> tab -> выводится consle.log, а как сделать так, что бы можно было выделить переменную, которая меня интересует и после горячей клавиши вывести автоматом ее в console.log ?

Answer (score 0):

Можно создать соответствующий [Surround template](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2018.3/using-live-templates.html#param), вроде

```
console.log($SELECTION$)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Такие темплейты применяются к выделенному куску кода с помощью `Ctrl+Alt+J` (**Code | Surround With Live Template...**).

Еще существуют т.н. [Postfix](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2018.3/settings-postfix-completion.html) темплейты - просто пишете `myVar.log` и нажимаете табуляцию => получается `console.log(myVar)`